# Can we create an apk without an user interface in android

Tags: android, user-interface, service, background

I want to create an apk, without an user interface in android. And I need to start a Service as soon as the Applicaton gets installed on the Device. Is there any possible way to create an apk without UI.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> And I need to start a Service as soon as the Applicaton gets installed on the Device.

Fortunately, that is not possible for an app installed through normal channels (e.g., the Play Store), for security reasons, [since Android 3.1](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols). Nothing of your app will run until something on the device uses an explicit `Intent` to start up one of your components, and that most certainly does not occur when your app is installed.

You are welcome to build your hardware, or your own custom ROM, that has your app pre-installed. In that case, you can arrange to be able to run right away.

Answer (score -2):

yes, you have juste to create a Service or a BrodcastReceiver which do something you want

Comment: Not since [Android 3.1](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols).