# Can android app do some work without first time launch ( Running it for first time)?

Tags: android, android-activity

Hey i wanna know if android apps are abble to perform some work like send data to there server accessing system tool and using all permissions it have requested for?
The scenario is, i install an app from google play successfully. I won't open that app. But i want it to contact its server and exchange some data and use all other  permissions. Is this possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29719337/115145

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it using broadcast reciever no need to run the app just regester for some broadcast reciever and wait for that to broadcast to your reciever and you can call whatever task you want in that reciever class... i will make it one and test it and post the github link in comment

Answer (score 0):

No, the app needs to be run once in order for you to perform the specified actions, merely installing would not be enough.